# Flutter: How to create parallelogram rounded in button

Tags: flutter, button

How to create parallelogram rounded in button like this image?

[image]

Comment: using custom painter or you can use package. 
https://pub.dev/packages/shaped_buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I fix this to create a button that supports the image as a background.